# Hyper-V Host Shutdown script

Tags: windows-server-2012, virtual-machines, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v-server-2012

So I have a cluster for Hyper-V and am working on a script to move all active VMs to a host over the weekend, put the hosts in maintenance mode, and then poweroff all but one of those hosts for the weekend..

I know that the PS VirtualMachineManager module contains things like 'Get-SCVMHost' Stop-SCVMHost, etc. but I can't figure out how to turn off the machine host and power it back on. Is this something which has to be done with IPMI? If so, I can't find the cmdlet to use to pipe credentials/info.

Any help or articles would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand. You're going to move them to a particular Hyper-V host and then power off your Hyper-V hosts. Why move the VM's then?

Comment: We have 4 hyper-V hosts. There are only a few VMs which need to stay on over the weekend. During the week there are quite a few. The goal is moved the few VMs which stay on over the weekend to one Hyper-V host and then power the other Hyper-V hosts off to save power over the weekend (and to make scheduling updates to firmware, etc. easier) @joeqwerty

Comment: Oh, so you're not shutting down **all** of your Hyper-V hosts. You didn't state that in your question.

Comment: Updating :) Also we have SCVMM.

Comment: Honestly, if you're in a position where you need to turn off a couple servers to save money you should look at hosting services or cloud IaaS.

Comment: @Colyn1337 - We have a HUGE lab with ~10 full racks. 1 of those racks is hyper-V. It will save non-trivial amounts of money.